# Extract a String using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

```
[0-6, 1-3][01-20, 22-23]22/123
```

From the above input, I would like to extract the following the following texts.

```
0-6, 1-3
01-20, 22-23
22
123
```

The following code snippets extracts the required texts excepts the first one.

```
    Pattern depArrHours = Pattern.compile("^(\\[(.+)\\]){2}(.+)\\/(.+)$");
    Matcher matcher = depArrHours.matcher("[0-6, 1-3][01-20, 22-23]22/123");
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
    }
```

Output:

```
[0-6, 1-3][01-20, 22-23]22/123
[01-20, 22-23]
01-20, 22-23
22
123
```

Can you please help me to fix my regex pattern to extract the first part also(0-6, 1-3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try specifying each `(\\[(.+)\\])` separate instead of `{2}`:

```
Pattern depArrHours = Pattern.compile("^(\\[(.+)\\])(\\[(.+)\\])(.+)\\/(.+)$");
Matcher matcher = depArrHours.matcher("[0-6, 1-3][01-20, 22-23]22/123");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(6));
}
```

Output :

```
[0-6, 1-3][01-20, 22-23]22/123
[0-6, 1-3]
0-6, 1-3
[01-20, 22-23]
01-20, 22-23
22
123
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify each of the first 2 groups separately:

```
Pattern depArrHours = Pattern.compile("^(\\[(.+)\\])(\\[(.+)\\])(.+)\\/(.+)$");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the pattern

```
 \\[([^\\]]*)\\]|(([0-9]*)/([0-9]*))
```

and use it with `matcher.find()`

```
Pattern depArrHours = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]*)\\]|(([0-9]*)/([0-9]*))");
Matcher matcher = depArrHours.matcher("[0-6, 1-3][01-20, 22-23]22/123");
while (matcher.find()) {
    String group = matcher.group(1);
        if (group == null) {
            // matched 22/123
            System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
        } else {
            // matched [0-6, 1-3] or [01-20, 22-23]
            System.out.println(group);
        }
}
```

Output

```
0-6, 1-3
01-20, 22-23
22
123
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
    String input="[0-6, 1-3][01-20, 22-23]22/123";
    String[] arr=input.replace('[', ' ').split("[\\]/]");
    for (String string : arr) {
        System.out.println(string.trim());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    String  k ="[0-6, 1-3][01-20, 22-23]22/123";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]*)\\]|([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(k);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println((m.group(1)!=null)?m.group(1):m.group(2)+"\n"+m.group(3));   
    }
```

The Regex `\\[([^\\]]*)\\]|([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)` can be represented as

[image]

*Output*:

```
0-6, 1-3
01-20, 22-23
22
123
```